# Docker Daemon startup error using clustering in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

I am trying to deploy a Swarm manually in EC2 using Consul as the keystore.
Here is my Consul startup:

```
sudo docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
sudo docker -H tcp://54.218.52.98:2375 run -d -p 8500:8500 -h consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

I am using the following to start a docker daemon on the Swarm master. I am running in EC2 with Ubuntu 15.04.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
sudo docker daemon --cluster-store=consul:///54.218.52.98:8500 --cluster-advertise=eth0:2375 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &
```

I am getting the following error on startup of the master daemon:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-164:~$ WARN[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs" 
INFO[0000] Initializing discovery without TLS           
INFO[0000] API listen on [::]:2375                      
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
ERRO[0000] discovery error: Unexpected watch error      
ERRO[0000] Registering as "172.31.12.164:2375" in discovery failed: cannot set or renew session for ttl, unable to operate on sessions 
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
INFO[0000] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.1/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.
..
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=a34a1d5 execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=aufs version=1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you check on aws ifconfig you will notice your external IP is not linked directly to eth interface.

I would suggest to --cluster-store consul://127.0.0.1:8500